# Unity Android game crash - java.lang.Error

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I've published an Android game recently and I've just seen a crash report on Google Play Console. I also know that the game crashes on loading on some devices (Samsung Galaxy S3 for example). Can anyone tell me what it means and why these crashes happen? Does it have something to do with the loading of textures? The game is 23 mb large and no textures are above 2048x2048. Thanks.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain]
Unity version     : 5.4.0f3
Device model      : LGE Nexus 4
Device fingerprint: google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48T/2237560:user/release-keys

Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 8d9ea9d0
Build fingerprint: 'google/occam/mako:5.1.1/LMY48T/2237560:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 10473, tid: 10530, name: main  >>> com.vies.shapeimpact <<<
r0 8d9ea9d0  r1 8d9eb000  r2 fffffe8c  r3 8d9eb000
r4 8d9ea9d0  r5 00000001  r6 8d9eaffc  r7 a477a4cc
r8 95a3008c  r9 00000000  sl 12d1dc30  fp af7ae804
ip afb41ee0  sp af7ae7d8  lr afa62e34  pc afa62da4  cpsr 753a3036

at libmono.002b3da4(Native Method)
at libmono.GC_push_all_stack(GC_push_all_stack:72)
at libmono.002bcabc(Native Method)
at libmono.002bcb8c(Native Method)
at libmono.002b88f8(Native Method)
at libmono.002b58ec(Native Method)
at libmono.002b21e0(Native Method)
at libmono.002ac2b4(Native Method)
at libmono.002abd98(Native Method)
at libmono.002acb5c(Native Method)
at libmono.002acbfc(Native Method)
at libmono.mono_gc_collect(mono_gc_collect:40)
at libmono.mono_domain_finalize(mono_domain_finalize:96)
at libmono.00024c10(Native Method)
at libmono.mono_jit_cleanup(mono_jit_cleanup:20)
at libunity.0037bc28(Native Method)
at libunity.003dc448(Native Method)
at libunity.0050a5a4(Native Method)
at libunity.0050c478(Native Method)
at data@app@com.00439c4f(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is accessing memory outside of its address space. This is most likely an invalid pointer access.
I am not sure if you have a leak or problems with loading in objects but I think it is a good idea to check your loading times and use a profiler to see if there are any memory issues.

Try to load certain objects at later times or use Async operations to load the objects individually and after each other.

Here are some links you can use.

[Profiler Manual Unity3d](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html)

[Async object loading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAsync.html)

[Async scene loading](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html)

This is still really broad as answer but I hope it will help.